# AppStore rejected my app because of advertisingIdentifier

Tags: ios, xcode5, appstore-approval

I have a problem with uploading an app to AppStore. It rejects my app because of advertisingIdentifier.

I have searched this method like "*grep -r advertisingIdentifier .*" However, I didn't find anything.

Third party libraries that I have used

1. JSPImagePicker - https://github.com/jpsim/JPSImagePickerController
2. AFNetworking - https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Any suggestions?

P.S. I used Flurry library as well, but then I removed it from my project completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check in Itunes Connect the following:

[image]

Do you use any ads in your app ? (iAd, Google AdMob, ... ?)

Comment: No, I don't use iAD and Google AdMob. But your answer with iTunesConnect should work!

Comment: Ok ;) hope it will be ok for you :)